# Installing circuit for tanning bed 220v 30 amp

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm installing a circuit for a tanning bed to treat my son's psoriasis but I've seen some conflicting info regarding proper wire gauge.  Would it be correct to use 10ga copper or 8ga alu or do I need a larger gauge?  I'll be using about 30-40' of wiring.  Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: What plug does the tanning bed provide, or is it hardwired?

Answer (score 1):

For a 240V/30A circuit, 10 AWG copper is indeed correct (it's the same stuff you'd pull for a dryer hookup).  You'll want to use 10/3 NM (instead of 10/2) so that you can have the option of converting the circuit to 120/240V 30A or installing a subpanel at a later date.